# How to give a bound e.g $\leq \epsilon$ in $e^{\frac{M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon)}{2\delta}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$\epsilon$ in $$e^{(M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon))/(2\delta)}$$

I know that $e^{M^2\times \log_e \epsilon}$ would result in $\epsilon^{M^2}$

But I am confused what to do with $2\delta$ denominator and squared log term $\log_e^2$.

I need to show that this expression is $\leq \epsilon$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{(M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon))/(2\delta)}$$ One has

$$\begin{cases}\frac{M^2\log_e(\epsilon)}{2\delta}=\log_e(\epsilon)^{M^2}\\\frac{M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon)}{2\delta}=\log_e(\epsilon)^{\frac{M^2\ln (\epsilon)}{2\delta}}\end{cases}$$

Hence the first expression becomes $$e^{\log_e(\frac{M^4\log_e(\epsilon)}{4(\delta)^2})}$$

Thus you want to have $$\frac{M^4\log_e(\epsilon)}{4(\delta)^2}\le \epsilon$$ This is not possible if you don't have information about $M$ and $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is true
as written.

If
$e^{(M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon))/(2\delta)}
\to 0
$,
then we have to have
$(M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon))/(2\delta)
\to -\infty
$.

But
$M^2 \log_e (\epsilon) + M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon)
=M^2 \log_e (\epsilon)(1+ M^2 \log_e (\epsilon))
$
and the two terms in this product
("$M^2 \log_e (\epsilon)$"
and
"$1+ M^2 \log_e (\epsilon)$")
are both negative
for small $\epsilon$,
so their product is
positive,
while we want the product
to be negative.

If the sign of
$M^2 \log_e^2 (\epsilon)
$
was "-"
instead of
"+",
then it would be OK.